# grub held back from update for weeks

Tags: apt, upgrade, grub-efi, held-packages

the two packages "*grub-efi-amd64-bin*" and "*grub-efi-amd64-signed*" have been held back from being updated(upgraded) by apt for more than a week now maybe two weeks.

sometimes when the linux image gets updated, some packages get stuck on being held back and I have to force upgrade them. but this has never happened with a package as vital as my bootloader.

I am worried my computer won't turn on again if i force the upgrade.

what should I do? I am greatly worried.

EDIT: I am using kubuntu 22.04.01
this is the error text

```
The following packages have been kept back: 
grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed
```

the newer versions according to muon package manager, belong to a repo called jammy-updates
[image: versions for jammy and jammy-updates]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Can you edit and post the full error message which says grub has been held back?

Comment: there edited it

Comment: I had a problem with these packages on 10/27/22 on one of my 20.04 computers. It turned out to be because my EFI partition did not have the `boot` and `esp` flags set on it. It had the `msftdata` flag set on it. I have no idea why that never caused a problem before, the computer has had 20.04 installed on it for over a year.

Comment: You can check your /var/log/apt for the term.log to see if you got any errors like I did when it tried to install the packages. The errors were confusing and unhelpful, like "The GRUB boot loader was previously installed to a disk that is no longer present, or whose unique identifier has changed".

Comment: I have seen this is several Jammy (upgraded) installs, but not sure of the cause. They all have correct flags on the EFI partition.